# Access asp.net class using jquery Ajax

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I use Jquery.Ajax to access page methods as written in this article:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

but i was wondering if there is a way to access a class file (.cs) directly without going through the code behind

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way. AJAX runs on the client and is server side agnostic. This means that AJAX doesn't know what a `.cs` file means. AJAX sends an HTTP request to a server side handler. If you are using ASP.NET on the server this handler could be either a generic handler (`IHttpHandler`) or a WebForm.

So the easiest way to expose the functionality contained in this .cs file would be to write a custom generic handler and then send an AJAX request to this handler.

For example:

```
public class MyHandler : IHttpHandler
{
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        var response = context.Response;
        response.ContentType = "application/json";
        response.Write(new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(new
        {
            result = SomeClass.GetResult()
        }));
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
        get { return true; }
    }
}
```

Now you could send an AJAX request to `/myhandler.ashx`.